# Node.js : bmfont2json is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I understand that this question has been asked countless times already but I cannot find the what is wrong in my case. Below is the code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var bmfont2json = require('bmfont2json');

var data = fs.readFileSync('Bitmap Font' + '/Roboto.fnt');
var obj = bmfont2json(data);

var json = JSON.stringify( obj );
```

This results in the error `bmfont2json`is not a function. Does anyone know the error in the above? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code on my machine, I did some changes (`var data = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/Bitmap Font' + '/Roboto.fnt');`) in your code.

**Please try below code:**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var bmfont2json = require('bmfont2json');
var data = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/Bitmap Font' + '/Roboto.fnt');
var obj = bmfont2json(data);
var json = JSON.stringify( obj );
console.log(json);
```

**example.fnt:**

```
info face="Arial" size=32 bold=0 italic=0 charset="" unicode=1 stretchH=100 smooth=1 aa=1 padding=0,0,0,0 spacing=1,1 outline=0
common lineHeight=32 base=26 scaleW=256 scaleH=256 pages=0 packed=0 alphaChnl=1 redChnl=0 greenChnl=0 blueChnl=0
chars count=0
```

**When you will replace your .fnt file with example the output will be:**

```
{  "pages":[],
   "chars":[],
   "kernings":[],
   "info":"face":"Arial", 
   "size":32,
   "bold":0,
   "italic":0,
   "charset":"",
   "unicode":1,
   "stretchH":100,
   "smooth":1,
   "aa":1,
   "padding":[0,0,0,0],
   "spacing":[1,1], 
   "outline":0},
   "common":{
              "lineHeight":32,
              "base":26,
              "scaleW":256,
              "scaleH":256,
              "pages":0,
              "packed":0, 
              "alphaChnl":1,
              "redChnl":0, 
              "greenChnl":0, 
              "blueChnl":0
             }
}
```

Try above code and then let me know.

Comment: If above code is not working then please change your Robot.fnt file with example.fnt. I have written example.fnt file.

Comment: Still the same error, not sure what's going on. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Ohhh,  In my machine working fine. Ok let me see again.

Comment: Ok thanks, let me have a look again. I'm sure I've done something wrong.

Comment: What node command did you use to output the file? I believe that's where I went wrong.

Comment: node fileName.js    (  You can try with my code and then rectify the mistakes.  )

You can replace your code with this after saving example.fnt file in your directory  var data = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/example.fnt');

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm doing exactly that but the console returns "Not enough non-option arguments: got 0, need at least 1". I've tried `-o "my file path"` which returns the "Not a function" error.

Comment: Thanks I fixed the issue. Turns out I installed the wrong npm package. LOL. Cannot believe my own stupidity.

Comment: Ohhh Its ok Mr.Lord Goderick . Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

As Bulkan and Maynank have already mentioned, you should not include `.js` at the end of the name of an NPM core module:

```
var bmfont2json = require('bmfont2json');
```

**However, what you're really doing wrong is this:**

```
var obj = bmfont2json(data);
```

Because this function is from the `bmfont2json` module, the correct code you be as follows:

```
var obj = bmfont2json.bmfont2json(data);
```

Notice that you are doing this the same way you did `var data = fs.readFileSync(blah blah blah);`. Since `readFileSync()` is a function in the `fs` module, you used `fs.readFileSync()` instead of just `readFileSync()`. This is how you use functions from *any* module in Node.js.

Therefore, the correct code is as follows:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var bmfont2json = require('bmfont2json.js');

var data = fs.readFileSync('Bitmap Font' + '/Roboto.fnt');
var obj = bmfont2json(data);

var json = JSON.stingify( obj );
```

Comment: Thanks so much but now the error becomes `bmfont2json.bmfont2json` is not a function.

Comment: @LordGoderick I just realized that the `bmfont2json` package was last updated more that two years ago, and was downloaded *only 35 times* this month. The author has probably abandoned the project, and I strongly discourage you from using it. :)

Comment: Ye, I'm using another one now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try importing `bmfont2json` as follows;

```
var bmfont2json = require('bmfont2json');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the require statement that you have written is wrong `var bmfont2json = require('bmfont2json.js');`

The correct way is to not include .js like this `var bmfont2json = require('bmfont2json');`

Answer (score 0):

```
var bmfont2json = require('bmfont2json');
```

as i believe you are using bmfont2json npm.

For more, you can refer to:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bmfont2json

Comment: did you run command to install package first: npm install bmfont2json -g

Comment: Yes I did that first.